# Kotlin `launch` statement only compiles inside a `runBlocking`

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using the latest version of Kotlin, and am trying to use coroutines with Android DataStore. I am not a coroutine expert. I have read that you shouldn't use `runBlocking`, because it suspends the entire thread.

But I am totally puzzled by the fact that the following compiles and runs fine:

```
runBlocking {
    launch {
        shouldBypassSplashScreen = mainViewModel.isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked()
    }
}
```

But this, which is the same code as above without the `runBlocking`,  gets a compile error, telling me that `launch` is undefined:

```
launch {
    shouldBypassSplashScreen = mainViewModel.isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked()
}
```

That's really the only reason I'm using `runBlocking`, because I can't get past the compile errors without it.

Answer (score 2):

[launch](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) is an extension on CoroutineScope. Hence, you need to call it with a CoroutineScope object.

[runBlocking](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) takes a lambda as its last argument with a CoroutineScope as the receiver, which is why it works in that case.

You need some `CoroutineScope` to call `launch` with - maybe a `lifecycleScope` if you're in a `Lifecycle` object, `viewLifeCycleScope` if you're in a `Fragment`, or the viewmodel's `viewmodelScope`.

```
mostAppropriateScopeToUseInThisCase.launch {
    shouldBypassSplashScreen = mainViewModel.isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked()
}
```

EDIT:

> I'm in a Jetpack Compose composable. All I'm trying to do is wait for an option to be read from an Android DataStore, which is why I need to be async.

Disclaimer: I've only briefly looked into Compose. But ...

I don't think you should be running `suspend` functions in a composable. My understanding is you have some state object that is used in the composable and that state is updated by your view model asynchronously.

Something like:

```
// ViewModel
class ViewModel {
    val shouldBypassSplashScreen by mutableStateOf(false)

    init {
        viewmodelScope.launch {
            shouldBypassSplashScreen = datastore.shouldBypassSplashScreen
        }
    }
 }
```

Then your composable just checks the `shouldBypassSplashScreen` property on the ViewModel and recomposes if the state changes. No need for corouties in the composable.

Again, I'm new to Compose so that might not be 100% correct, but maybe it points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @dominicoder! I'm in a Jetpack Compose composable. All I'm trying to do is wait for an option to be read from an Android DataStore, which is why I need to be async. Not sure what scope to use there.

Comment: Even when I import a lifecycle scope, I'm getting a compiler error:
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope

                    lifecycleScope {
                        launch {
                            shouldBypassSplashScreen = mainViewModel.isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked()
                        }
                    }

Says it can't find lifecycleScope.

Comment: Sorry for the fact that comments aren't formatted at all.
All I really want to do is call Android DataStore to get a value from an option, but it's a suspend function, so it tells me I need to be in a coroutine or another suspend function. I just must not be understanding this, it seems like it should be simple, but it's not.

Comment: What was wrong with the LaunchedEffect solution in my answer to your other question? Think about your own experience with apps. When anything is being loaded, for instance a web page, the UI of the system doesn’t completely freeze. It shows some loading indicator, often animated, and allows you to back out of what you’re doing. As an app author, now it’s up to you to implement this. Decide what UI you want to show while something is retrieved and continue without blocking (freezing the whole UI).

Comment: For something that will happen really fast, like a DataStore Boolean, I think it’s appropriate to simply show a blank screen while you await the data because it will arrive so quickly.

Comment: @DaveWesterman I updated my answer with a suggestion for your case.

Comment: @dominicoder You can't `remember` outside a Composable.

Comment: OK - removed the `remember` - hopefully the idea is still sound.